# KDE: Increase font size on laptop monitor if external monitors are connected

Tags: linux, kde, kubuntu

What the title says. Can this be done easily? How? I'm using Kubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Take a look at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162603/how-do-i-change-system-wide-font-settings-in-kubuntu

Comment: @bZezzz Thanks, but my scenario is more complicated.